# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, gcc

I'm using CLion with GCC 7.8 for coding in C++. We have this code, which using for "rendering" image from *.OBJ files.

```
#ifndef __GEOMETRY_H__
#define __GEOMETRY_H__

#include <cmath>

template <class t> struct Vec2 {
    t x, y;
    Vec2<t>() : x(t()), y(t()) {}
    Vec2<t>(t _x, t _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
    Vec2<t>(const Vec2<t> &v) : x(t()), y(t()) { *this = v; }
    Vec2<t> & operator =(const Vec2<t> &v) {
        if (this != &v) {
            x = v.x;
            y = v.y;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Vec2<t> operator +(const Vec2<t> &V) const { return Vec2<t>(x+V.x, y+V.y); }
    Vec2<t> operator -(const Vec2<t> &V) const { return Vec2<t>(x-V.x, y-V.y); }
    Vec2<t> operator *(float f)          const { return Vec2<t>(x*f, y*f); }
    t& operator[](const int i) { if (x<=0) return x; else return y; }
    template <class > friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Vec2<t>& v);
};

template <class t> struct Vec3 {
    t x, y, z;
    Vec3<t>() : x(t()), y(t()), z(t()) { }
    Vec3<t>(t _x, t _y, t _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}
    template <class u> Vec3<t>(const Vec3<u> &v);
    Vec3<t>(const Vec3<t> &v) : x(t()), y(t()), z(t()) { *this = v; }
    Vec3<t> & operator =(const Vec3<t> &v) {
        if (this != &v) {
            x = v.x;
            y = v.y;
            z = v.z;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Vec3<t> operator ^(const Vec3<t> &v) const { return Vec3<t>(y*v.z-z*v.y, z*v.x-x*v.z, x*v.y-y*v.x); }
    Vec3<t> operator +(const Vec3<t> &v) const { return Vec3<t>(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z); }
    Vec3<t> operator -(const Vec3<t> &v) const { return Vec3<t>(x-v.x, y-v.y, z-v.z); }
    Vec3<t> operator *(float f)          const { return Vec3<t>(x*f, y*f, z*f); }
    t       operator *(const Vec3<t> &v) const { return x*v.x + y*v.y + z*v.z; }
    float norm () const { return std::sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z); }
    Vec3<t> & normalize(t l=1) { *this = (*this)*(l/norm()); return *this; }
    t& operator[](const int i) { if (i<=0) return x; else if (i==1) return y; else return z; }
    template <class > friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Vec3<t>& v);
};

typedef Vec2<float> Vec2f;
typedef Vec2<int>   Vec2i;
typedef Vec3<float> Vec3f;
typedef Vec3<int>   Vec3i;

template <> template <> Vec3<int>::Vec3(const Vec3<float> &v);
template <> template <> Vec3<float>::Vec3(const Vec3<int> &v);


template <class t> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Vec2<t>& v) {
    s << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ")\n";
    return s;
}

template <class t> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Vec3<t>& v) {
    s << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << ")\n";
    return s;
}

#endif //__GEOMETRY_H__
```

This template used in my main.cpp file, something like that:

```
void triangle(Vec3i t0, Vec3i t1, Vec3i t2, TGAImage &image, TGAColor color, int *zbuffer) {
    if (t0.y == t1.y && t0.y == t2.y) return;
    // sort point by Y coordinate
    if (t0.y > t1.y) std::swap(t0, t1);
    if (t0.y > t2.y) std::swap(t0, t2);
    if (t1.y > t2.y) std::swap(t1, t2);

    int total_height = t2.y - t0.y;

    for (int i=0; i<total_height; i++) {
        bool second_half = i > t1.y - t0.y || t1.y == t0.y;
        int segment_height = second_half ? t2.y - t1.y : t1.y - t0.y;

        float alpha = (float)i / total_height;
        float beta  = (float)(i - (second_half ? t1.y - t0.y : 0)) / segment_height;

        Vec3i A =               t0 + Vec3f(t2 - t0) * alpha;
        Vec3i B = second_half ? t1 + Vec3f(t2 - t1) * beta : t0 + Vec3f(t1 - t0) * beta;

        if (A.x > B.x) std::swap(A, B);

        for (int j=A.x; j<=B.x; j++) {
            float phi = B.x == A.x ? 1. : (float)(j - A.x) / (float)(B.x - A.x);
            Vec3i P = Vec3f(A) + Vec3f(B - A) * phi;
            int idx = P.x + P.y * width;
            // Z-buffer
            if (zbuffer[idx] < P.z) {
                zbuffer[idx] = P.z;
                image.set(P.x, P.y, color);
            }
        }
    }
}

void add_light_zbuffer(Vec3f light_dir, Model &model, TGAImage &image, int* zbuffer) {
    for (int i=0; i<model.nfaces(); i++) {
        std::vector<int> face = model.face(i);
        Vec3i screen_coords[3];
        Vec3f world_coords[3];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            Vec3f v = model.vert(face[j]);
            screen_coords[j] = Vec3i((v.x + 1.) * width  / 2.,
                                     (v.y + 1.) * height / 2.,
                                     (v.z + 1.) * depth  / 2.);
            world_coords[j] = v;
        }

        // calculate light intensity
        Vec3f n = (world_coords[2] - world_coords[0]) ^ (world_coords[1] - world_coords[0]);
        n.normalize();
        float intensity = n * light_dir;
        // and apply it on image
        if (intensity > 0) {
            triangle(screen_coords[0], screen_coords[1], screen_coords[2], image,
                     TGAColor((unsigned char)(intensity * 255),
                              (unsigned char)(intensity * 255),
                              (unsigned char)(intensity * 255),
                              (unsigned char) 255),
                     zbuffer);
        }
    }
}


void scene_3d_zbuffer() {
    TGAImage render(width, height, TGAImage::RGB);
    Model* model = new Model("../assets/african_head.obj");

    int* zbuffer = new int[width * height];
    for (int i=0; i<width * height; i++) {
        zbuffer[i] = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    }

    Vec3f light_dir = Vec3f(0, 0, -1);
    add_light_zbuffer(light_dir, *model, render, zbuffer);

    render.flip_vertically();
    render.write_tga_file("output3_2.tga");
    delete zbuffer;
    delete model;
}
```

But after start building by CMake 3.2.2, I taken this messages in my console:

```
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable /Users/savicvalera/code/LearnComputerGraphics/bin/Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces
[ 66%] Built target Lesson_1_Bresenham_algorithm
Built target Lesson_2_Trinagles_rasterization
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Vec3<float>::Vec3<int>(Vec3<int> const&)", referenced from:
      triangle(Vec3<int>, Vec3<int>, Vec3<int>, TGAImage&, TGAColor, int*) in main.cpp.o
  "Vec3<int>::Vec3<float>(Vec3<float> const&)", referenced from:
      triangle(Vec3<int>, Vec3<int>, Vec3<int>, TGAImage&, TGAColor, int*) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/savicvalera/code/LearnComputerGraphics/bin/Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And my question is: what happens with code, and why build failed every time?

Comment: You are trying to use some library that I don't recognise as you don't show any `include` filenames or anything that helps identify it. And there seems to be something wrong in your CMAkefile which you don't show either. Mmmm.... can you show the linker settings you are using and give details of the libraries you are hoping to use?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah, thanks for tip. I've added link to "geometry.h" in my CMake file. But now taken message with Vec3 constructor:  "out-of-line constructor for 'Vec3' cannot have template arguments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this issue necessary add links on cpp/h files into CMake file. For example, in this situation was:

```
project(Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES src/IntroCG/Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces/main.cpp)
add_executable(Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces ${SOURCE_FILES}
               src/IntroCG/tgaimage.cpp src/IntroCG/tgaimage.h
               src/IntroCG/model.cpp src/IntroCG/model.h
               src/IntroCG/painter.cpp src/IntroCG/painter.h)
```

and became

```
project(Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES src/IntroCG/Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces/main.cpp)
add_executable(Lesson_3_Deleting_hidden_surfaces ${SOURCE_FILES}
               src/IntroCG/geometry.cpp src/IntroCG/geometry.h
               src/IntroCG/tgaimage.cpp src/IntroCG/tgaimage.h
               src/IntroCG/model.cpp src/IntroCG/model.h
               src/IntroCG/painter.cpp src/IntroCG/painter.h)
```